# Combinations to find a given sum

Tags: google-sheets, calculator

I have a range of values ( 5 - 19), and each value occurs a different number of times (eg 5 - 2x, 6 - 2x, 7 - 5x, etc.).

I've found various combination calculators on the web, but they are limited in certain ways. Either they don't find a given sum and just list all possible combinations, or they list all combinations for a given sum but don't allow specifying each value's occurrence.

Any tips/suggestions?

Thanks, Pat

Edit: I would also like to specify that the "sample size" equals 3, eg these combinations of 3 values equals 40.

Edit 2: After further reflection, I think I can refine my question a bit more.

I have 80 objects in total, and each is assigned a value ranging from 5 - 19. I have multiple objects of each value. I would like to know the combinations of these 80 objects to equal 40, limiting each combination to 3 or 4 objects, and limiting the combinations by the occurrence of each value.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). This sounds like a variation of the [Knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem). There is no known efficient algorithm to give an optimal solution in the general case. A _good enough_ solution may be possible, but that depends on many details. Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with _realistic-looking_ data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lh2AnQ-TrQ-VGcfwRZ3RaQIZSgVsBjtdSN6KL0XwVko/edit?usp=sharing

Do you mean something like this? Each cell is an individual object, and is the actual data I'm working with. Let me know if you need any other info.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Your spreadsheet is a great start, but @doubleunary also asked that you _[show] your hand-entered **expected results**_.  Would you please add this to your spreadsheet.

Comment: Google has a product called [OR-Tools](https://developers.google.com/optimization) - _open source software for combinatorial optimization_. The documentation includes a worked guide on [The Knapsack Problem](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/knapsack). The main hiccup that I can see is that it relies on Python, C++, Java or C# libraries. No JavaScript here and no example of a link to Google Sheets.

Comment: Pat, have you read [How do you automatically add values in an optimal order based on a criteria?](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/135960806/how-do-you-automatically-add-values-in-an-optimal-order-based-on-a-criteria?hl=en&msgid=135970629) on Google Docs Editors Help? In that case, the OP said _After some deliberation, using Google sheets to do what I wanted to may not be the best solution. The alternative is probably to program my own tool to do this or look for other ready-made tools._

Comment: Tedinoz, thanks for you input, especially sharing the link to OR-Tools. I do have some programming experience, including brief exposure to Python, but I'm no programmer by any means. Based on yours and doubleunary's replies it seems like I'm asking a little too much. The other web calculators are "good enough" in the sense that they return results like

Comment: {5, 16, 19} (5, 17, 18} {6, 15, 19} etc.

but I was hoping for a way to refine those results by limiting the number of times a particular value was used. An example would be since 5 only occurs twice, what are the two best combinations that use the number 5 while maintaining optimal results (obtaining 40 the largest amount of times). Asking too much, I think. My application is personal hobby time rather than work-related, so I'm not terribly disappointed. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to solve a [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is a variation of the [knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem).

The problem is [NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-completeness) and there is no known efficient algorithm to give an optimal solution in the general case.

A good enough solution is possible in many cases, but if the sample spreadsheet you shared is realistic, I would say that the subsets you want cannot practically be calculated using plain vanilla spreadsheet formulas.

To understand why, see the new '[Simple subsets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lh2AnQ-TrQ-VGcfwRZ3RaQIZSgVsBjtdSN6KL0XwVko/edit#gid=202251444)' sheet in your sample spreadsheet. It finds 153 different ways to combine exactly three terms so that their sum is 40 (including duplicates like `05 + 17 + 18` and `05 + 18 + 17`).

The example is very simplistic, and does not take the number of available terms into account. It uses these formulas:

`=query( unique( flatten( transpose(Sheet1!A1:O4) ) ), "where Col1 is not null limit 1000", 0 )`

`=arrayformula( unique( query( { flatten( trim(A2:A16) & " + " & transpose(trim(A2:A16)) ), flatten( A2:A16 + transpose(A2:A16) ) }, "where Col2 <= 40 order by Col2 asc limit 1000", 0 ) ) )`

`=arrayformula( unique( query( { flatten( trim(C2:C226) & " + " & transpose(trim(A2:A16)) ), flatten( D2:D226 + transpose(A2:A16) ) }, "where Col2 = 40 order by Col1 asc limit 1000", 0 ) ) )`

To get a workable solution, you may want to use a proper combinatorial optimization package instead of a spreadsheet.

Comment: doubleunary, you've been very helpful, I'm grateful. Your insight into the problem I presented was indeed very educational. As stated in my response to Tedinoz, I think I'm asking too much and overly complicating a not-very-serious task. Sorting through the combinations presented by the afore-mentioned web calculators is tedious and annoying, but not particularly problematic.

Thanks again to both of you for your time, I do appreciate it. Hope you both enjoy the holiday season!